# How to upgrade the Kops version

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I am using `Kops` to setup my Kubernetes cluster.

This is how, I installed kops,

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/1.6.1/kops-linux-amd64
chmod +x kops-linux-amd64
sudo mv kops-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kops
```

My `Kubernetes` cluster is pretty old. Now, I want to upgrade it to latest version. I know that `kops upgrade cluster` works to upgrade the `Kubernetes`. But, before upgrading the `Kubernetes`, I want to make sure that my `Kops` version is latest.

Should I just remove running `kops`, that is

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/kops
```

then download the latest release and place it in `/usr/local/bin/`

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/1.11.0/kops-darwin-amd64
chmod +x kops-darwin-amd64
sudo mv kops-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kops
```

Is the above procedure correct ? If not, then what is the recommended way to upgrade the `Kops` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wget
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/1.11.0/kops-darwin-amd64
>   chmod +x kops-darwin-amd64 sudo mv kops-darwin-amd64
>   /usr/local/bin/kops

Here is a mistake you use `kops-darwin-amd64`  but you should  use

```
 wget https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/1.11.0/kops-linux-amd64
```

instead.

Comment: Is everything else fine ?

Comment: For Kops yes, but there could be problems with upgrading of your kubernetrs but it depends

Comment: update lastest version with wget "https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-linux-amd64"

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using mac try,

```
brew upgrade kops
```

Comment: I am not using Mac. I am using AWS EC2 Ubuntu